# Can't access WCF service through https

Tags: c#, wcf, https, windows-services

I setup a WCF application to be hosted by a Windows service. I got this to work correctly and I can navigate to it by going to http://127.0.0.1:1214. Here is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="NetworkPrintClient.PrintWebService" behaviorConfiguration="PrintServiceBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:1214/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="NetworkPrintClient.IPrintWebService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="PrintServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now I'd like to make this accessible at https://127.0.0.1:1214. After reading several articles about doing this, I end up with the config below. But, I can't browse to the application anymore. I just get a "This site can't be reached" error in Chrome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="NetworkPrintClient.PrintWebService" behaviorConfiguration="PrintServiceBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="https://127.0.0.1:1214/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="NetworkPrintClient.IPrintWebService" behaviorConfiguration="HttpBehavior" bindingConfiguration="PrintServiceHttpsBinding"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="PrintServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HttpBehavior">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="PrintServiceHttpsBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The article I used to get this far is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131048/WCF-self-hosted-service-over-HTTPS). I did the part at the bottom about making the certificate and mapping it to my IP and port. I also tried to get this to work with "localhost" and my actual IP address. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried accessing your service with the WCF Test Client? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe - I found that helpful in some cases. Also, I would recommend to start again from the working version you have above and then piece by piece glue in all the rest while making sure that every step still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You must to create a certificate selfhosted to localhost, you can use this command line in powersheel 
   **New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost", "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"** when you execute is gonna generate the thumbprint of certificate keep to associate to the port something like this "B80BE75765AA5739EAC63AAF67C32E5A3625FF19"
2. in window type "certificates" and click manage computer certificates and copy the certificate from personal\certificates to trusted root certification authorities\certificates
3. associate the certificate hash (thumbprint to the port) - **netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash={1} appid={2} certstore=MY** 0 - port - 1 - (the thumbprint generated by the certificate) 2 - {555b2e5f-4877-459b-bff2-60bb25898455} (GUID)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I believe it was step 2 that I was missing. I reviewed what I did following the guide I referenced, and at not point did I move my certificate to the trusted root. After doing that, everything worked like it was suppose to.